# Django queryset with bidirectional relations

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm struggling with making an efficient queryset with the following model:

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_connections')
    to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_connections')
    status = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

What I'm trying to do is, for a specified user, fetch a list of all his connections (so where he is either `from` or `to`) and annotate the status where he is `from` but also annotate the reverse status where he is `to`.

So for the example:

```
from |   to   |   status
------------------------
   A |      B |        1
   B |      A |        0
   C |      A |        2
   A |      D |        2
```

the results would be something like this:

```
user |      status | reverse_status
-----------------------------------
   B |           1 |              0
   C |        None |              2
   D |           2 |           None
```

The closest solution I've got to so far is something like this:

```
qs = Connection.objects.filter(from_id=a_id)

reverse_qs = Connection.objects.filter(from_id=OuterRef("to_id"), to_id=a_id)
qs = qs.annotate(reverse_status=Subquery(reverse_status.values("status")[:1]))
```

This almost gives me what I need but since the queryset is including only results where user A is `from`, the results obviously don't contain anything for user C (from the example table above).

I also tried exploring the route with using related_names like

```
User.objects.filter(Q(from_connections__to=a_id)|Q(to_connections__from=a_id).annotate...
```

but this approach didn't get me far.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this using Django ORM? Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

When you create a model having 2 `ForeignKey`s, you have to specify a `related_name`, Example :

```py
class Connection(models.Model):
    from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'from_connection')
    to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'to_connection')
    status = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

That will help in backwards relationships, more details in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually tried this (maybe I should update my question) but using `related_name` twice in a query (once `from` and once `to`) generates two outer joins and gives back 2 rows for bidirectional connection (A/B, B/A). Any specific ideas how to solve this?